# Jquery Library upgrade

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-ui, upgrade

I use older version of jquery like jquery-2.0.3.min.js which is older now i want to upgrade jquery-3.3.1.min.js so i added jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js but if i want to upgrade some other libraries like jquery-ui it will give me errors like

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation

i want to upgrade some other jquery libraries:

1. jquery.ui.touch-punch.js
2. jquery.easing.1.3.min.js
3. jquery.ztwitterfeed.js
4. jquery.simplyscroll.js

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I'm not able to re-create your issue. Can you post your code in a fiddle?

Comment: hello Jonathan Chaplin
issue are resolve as per below first answer the issue is i use carabiner for compress js library so now i just remove from carabiner and add js with script tag it will be work.

Answer (score 1):

First directly use CDN link for checking purpose.

If it's working properly then you might be compressing already minified version.

I've also faced the same issue & wasted a lot of time with my friend.

Reply back if you have any problem.